# Can I make a trip of 260 km across Japan with a pedal assist bike?

Tags: electric-bike

Just curious if it sounds crazy to use a PEDAL ASSIST E-Bike to make a trip across Japan...somewhere like 260KMs total.  Also what are some good bags (that don't make my back sweat so much) and pants I should where to make my bum nice and soft. I'm new to long distance riding.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, your question is really way too broad. Please see [ask] and ask one question per post. Do not hesitate to open musltiple posts if you have multiple questions. Do not ask for specific products but for properties of bags or similar.

Comment: Aside - Japan has excellent train services, and you can take a bike on them.  It may be more effective to ride to the station, entrain, and relax for an hour or so.

Comment: There are now e-bikes that **stop** when battery is out? I don't see any reason otherwise why you can't use any bike to go 260km over multiple days... Some [edit] with clarification of the restrictions could really help.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, but some are too heavy to get up modest hills unassisted with the gears they've got, not helped if the geometry is based on relaxed comfort rather than hard efforts

Comment: Not on a single battery charge and you need a rideable road. Apart that, why this could be any problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Just curious if it sounds crazy to use a PEDAL ASSIST E-Bike to make a trip across Japan...somewhere like 260KMs total

I find that on road e-bikes with around 500 watt-hour battery, and best low rolling resistance tires you can buy (Continental GP 5000 pumped to high pressure), the range varies between 75 and 150 km. 75 km is more realistic when tired and riding in city traffic. 150 km is more realistic when riding in countryside where you have to stop only very rarely, and not being tired.

260 kilometers requires a spare battery (around 3 kilograms) or the ability to stop somewhere to charge the battery (the charger has some weight too even though it's far lighter than 3 kilograms). Even the best e-bikes typically have at least 2.5 hours of charging time from empty to full, and even that might require buying a more powerful charger than the one that came with the bike.

> Also what are some good bags (that don't make my back sweat so much)

Avoid backpacks. They make your back sweat a lot. In contrast, a messenger bag causes only very minimal sweat, so little that it doesn't annoy you.

As for bags, I have two types that I use.

First is a messenger bag. I always carry it everywhere, including on the bike and off the bike. Perfect for carrying the mini pump, tools for emergency repairs, spare tube, wallet, mobile phone, keys (you don't want keys in your pocket as the sweat will dissolve metals that may cause allergic reactions), etc. Also the main compartment allows carrying a reasonable amount of stuff when being unprepared and not taking panniers with you. My choice for messenger bags is Marimekko Urbaani, costs around 150 euros/dollars/whatever. It can take any 13 inch laptop and some 14 inch laptops might fit too if they are small enough. Easiest to find in Finland (Marimekko is a Finnish brand), but I'm sure nowadays it can be ordered to other countries online.

I find my messenger bag makes for example saddle bags unneeded. The messenger bag has far more space for stuff.

Second is panniers of good quality. I use Ortlieb Back Roller Classic. They are waterproof if riding in the rain. You want to put the heavy and large stuff there, and the light and small stuff in the messenger bag. You can easily carry a pair of panniers when off the bike using the handles so that the panniers are back to back, using only one of your hands.

> pants I should where to make my bum nice and soft

Depends on the saddle. I use non cycling specific sports shorts. I find they work well enough if the saddle has a reasonable amount of padding. Usually when riding for long distances, the area that hurts the most are my feet. So even though they are not cycling specific, I find they don't limit my comfortable cycling distance at all.

However, nobody weighs cycling shorts but everyone weighs their bikes, so it has become trendy to supply bikes with ridiculously lightweight saddles, saddles that have practically no padding so they can be reasonably used only with cycling specific shorts that have a lot of padding. I find the trend ridiculous, as it just moves weight from one place to another place, from a place that is weighed to a place that is not weighed. The total weight probably stays about the same.

Comment: Thank you for an amazing answer!  My e-bike on HIGH pedal assist can go 109KM and on eco mode 222KM.  I suppose I can make the trip in 2 days or 3days or so if needed.  Don't think I could pull off something like that in one go lol.  Some parts through city and some parts through country. Tokyo to Nagano.  Do you have an links/videos to show me the stuff you talked about. (Amazing info)

Comment: *it has become trendy to supply bikes with ridiculously lightweight saddles* citation needed! My suspicion is that minimally-padded saddles are fitted because they're expected on race-style bikes (The Rules), but stock saddles on endurance bikes can be more padded than many road saddles

Comment: As for messenger bags combined with long distance, it all depends how much the OP is planning to ride per day.  Taking 10 days to do the trip, anything would do, maybe even for 5 days, but 1-2 days and you really don't want to have weight on your body, especially asymmetric weight